# JAVA build war in command prompt

Tags: java, gradle, war, command-prompt

I have java-project, the i've used intellij for this. Now i need to know how to build war for project in command prompt.

I want get some analogy for "war" command into idea gradle commands.

Comment: Locate your parent project in command prompt and type `gradle clean war`

Comment: i'm going to try

Comment: I've success with your answer. Tino, write your comment as answer. i will approve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Gradle's environment variable (GRADLE_HOME) is set in your system, then locate your parent project in command prompt and execute the below command

```
gradle clean war
```